# Displaying help through command line argument

Tags: python

I have a python program that I am running through command line arguments. I have used `sys` module.

Below is my `test.py` Python file where I am taking all the args:

```
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    files = sys.argv

get_input(files)
```

The `get_input` method is in another Python file where I have the `options` defined.

```
options = {

    '--case1': case1,
    '--case2': case2,

}


def get_input(arguments):

    for file in arguments[1:]:
        if file in options:
            options[file]()
        else:
            invalid_input(file)
```

To run:

```
python test.py --case1 --case2
```

My intentions are that I want to show the user all the commands in case they want to read the docs for that.

They should be able to read all the commands like they usually are in all the package for reading help, `python test.py --help` . With this they should be able to look into all the commands they can run.

How do I do this?

Comment: why not use `argparse`?

Comment: Most of the searches gave me sys.argv. So went through that :)

Comment: Thanks Chris_Rands . I am looking through `argparse` and think this is what I should have used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the best quality a Python developer can be proud of is to use built-in libraries instead of custom ones. So let's use [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/argparse.html):

```
import argparse

# define your command line arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='My application description')
parser.add_argument('--case1', help='It does something', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--case2', help='It does something else, I guess', action='store_true')

# parse command line arguments
args = parser.parse_args()

# Accessing arguments values
print('case1 ', args.case1)
print('case2 ', args.case2)
```

You can now use your cmd arguments like `python myscript.py --case1`

This comes with a default `--help` argument you can now use like: `python myscript.py --help` which will output:

```
usage: myscript.py [-h] [--case1] [--case2]

My application description

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --case1     It does something
  --case2     It does something else, I guess
```

Comment: Thanks Arount. This seems to be an apt choice :)

Comment: @themaster cool, be careful I just fixed a typo within the example code ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use option parser and add your options and related help information.

It has by default help option which shows all the available options which you have added.

The detailed document is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html). And below is the example.

```
from optparse import OptionParser

parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-f", "--file", dest="filename",
                  help="write report to FILE", metavar="FILE")
parser.add_option("-q", "--quiet",
                  action="store_false", dest="verbose", default=True,
                  help="don't print status messages to stdout")

(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: `optparse` has been deprecated since Python 3.2. For new code, use `argparse` instead.